# Pullbacks classified by morphisms of fundamental groups?

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a connected compact Lie group, $H$ a connected semisimple compact Lie group with $\tilde{H}$ its universal cover which is compact and simply connected. Let $\phi: G\to H$, and $\pi: \tilde{H}\to H$ and let $G'$ be the corresponding pullback, with $p: G'\to G$ and $\phi': G'\to \tilde{H}$ being the projections, which is the fibered product of $G$ and $\tilde{H}$ over $H$.

In short we consider the commutative diagram
$$\begin{array}{cc}
G'&\stackrel{\phi'}{\longrightarrow}&\tilde{H}\\
\downarrow{p} &&\downarrow{\pi}\\
G&\stackrel{\phi}{\longrightarrow}&H
\end{array}$$
I would like to understand the relationships between the different coverings $p: G'\to G$ and the morphisms $\pi_1(G)\to \pi_1(H)$ of fundamental groups induced by $\phi$. Does the latter classify the former? That is to say is there a bijection between the morphisms of fundamental groups $\pi_1(G)\to\pi_1(H)$ and the coverings $p:G'\to G$? Is the compactness hypothesis important?

Edit1: Here are my thoughts so far

If $\phi_0:G\to H$ and $\phi_1:G\to H$ are homotopic, they are actually conjugate because $G$ is compact. Therefore we get isomorphic pullbacks. But I am not familiar with algebraic topology, so perhaps the use of this result is too strong for the question asked. And I do not know if we actually get a bijection between morphisms of fundamental groups and homotopy class of function from $G$ to $H$ in that case.

Comment: I do not think your question is well-formulated. I think, what you mean to ask is: "Suppose that continuous homomorphisms $\phi_0, \phi_1: G\to H$ induce the same homomorphism of fundamental groups. Then the corresponding coverings $G_0\to G, G_1\to G$ are isomorphic." Is this what you have in mind? Then the answer has nothing to do with Lie groups and follows from the basic covering theory which you can find in any textbook on algebraic topology (say, Massey or Hatcher).

Comment: @MoisheCohen At last somebody reacts to my question! Thank you for your time. I think you are right: my question is not well formulated. First of all I would like to understand what depends of the context (compact Lie Groups, so with finite type abelian fundamental groups). Your comment seems to say that in one direction it is one very general result. Do you have a precise reference to point me in Hatcher? I found a result with only the hypothesis of G being paracompact and $\tilde{H}$ locally trivial bundle. Is it this one result. To be continued next comment ...

Comment: @MoisheCohen But I failed to find a result in the other direction, meaning that for each morphism of fundamental groups there is a commutative diagram that corresponds to it. By looking at projective space examples (that are compact Lie groups), it seems to me it does not work, so there is no bijection, just an injection. Am I right? (I add +1 to your comment)

Comment: The opposite direction is false: Not all homomorphisms $\pi_1(G)\to \pi_1(H)$ are induced by group homomorphisms $G\to H$. Maybe you have something else in mind, but I do not know what it is. Each homomorphism $\pi_1(G)\to \pi_1(H)$ induces a covering map $G'\to G$ such that the diagram in question commutes on the level of fundamental groups, is this what you wanted? Finiteness of fundamental groups and semisimplicity is irrelevant for the entire discusion so far.

Comment: @MoisheCohen I do not understand your sentence from "Each homomorphism" to "on the level of fundamental groups". Can you be more explicit? Apart from it, it is clear that you confirm to me that the homotopy type of commutative diagram described in the question only injects in $\text{Hom}(\pi_1(G),\pi_1(H))$. No bijection. And the Lie groups category is not important. If you can make it an answer (with an example of non surjectivity, and the most general category of objects on which it works), I will give you the bounty. Thank you again for your efforts!

Comment: Yes, I will just not right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the basic facts of the covering theory. In what follows, I will consider only path-connected semilocally-simply-connected topological spaces. (The latter means that for each point $x\in X$ and a neighborhood 
$U$ of $x$, there is a smaller neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that the natural map $\pi_1(V,x)\to \pi_1(U,x)$ is trivial.)

Let $p: X\to Y$ be a covering map  topological spaces. It induces a monomorphism of fundamental groups $p_*: \pi_1(X,x)\to G=\pi_1(Y, y)$, $y=p(x)$. The image group $p_*(\pi_1(X,x))$ is the **defining subgroup** of the covering $p$. Conversely, given any subgroup $H\le G$ there is a unique (up to an isomorphism) covering map $p: X\to Y$ with the defining group $H$.

Moreover, given a map $f: (Z,z)\to (Y,y)$ and a covering map $X\to Y$ with the defining subgroup $H\le G$, the map $f$ lifts to $X$ if and only if $f_*(\pi_1(Z,z))\le H$.

All this can be found in Hatcher or Massey or any other half-way decent textbook on algebraic topology.

One can specialize this setting as follows. Suppose that we have a map $f: (Y,y)\to (Y_1,y_1)$ of (pointed) path connected spaces. Then the kernel $H=ker(\pi_1(h_*))$ is a subgroup of $G= \pi_1(Y,y)$. The trivial subgroup of $\pi_1(Y_1,y_1)$ defines the universal covering $p_1: \tilde Y_1\to Y_1$. The subgroup $H$ defines a certain covering $p: Y'\to Y$. In view of the lifting property mentioned above, the map $f$ lifts to a map $\tilde f: Y'\to \tilde Y_1$ such that $p_1\circ \tilde f= p\circ f$. In other words, this is your fiber product diagram.

In particular, the map $\phi: \pi_1(Y,y)\to \pi_1(Y_1, y_1)$ uniquely determines the pull-back covering map $Y'\to Y$. Specializing further to the case of topological groups $Y, Y_1$ (say, Lie groups) as in your question, we obtain an injective map from $Hom(\pi_1(Y,y), \pi_1(Y_1, y_1))$ to the set of isomorphism classes of covering maps $Y'\to Y$. This map is, of course, not bijective even though $Y, Y_1$ have abelian fundamental groups (as topological groups do): Given two abelian groups $A, A_1$, not every subgroup $B< A$ is realized as the kernel of a homomorphism $A\to A_1$.

Even worse, even if there is a homomorphism $\phi: \pi_1(Y,y)\to \pi_1(Y_1, y_1)$ whose kernel is the given subgroup $N< \pi_1(Y,y)$, there is no reason to expect that there is a continuous group homomorphism $Y\to Y_1$ which induces $\phi$. Examples are easy to construct and I leave this to you.